# How can my array of students be displayed and also stop the input of students into the array?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to code a gradebook as a project. So far I have developed the code to calculate exam grades and display the outputs however,  I'm having trouble displaying my arrays once the user inputs the information (Student first and last name, ID and Exams) It wont display it. Also my code still wants to add user inputs once I click the cancel button on the browser. I would like the user inputs to stop once I hit the cancel button but how would I fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        //Initilization of Grades
        let grade = 0;
        //Start of the function
        studentArray();    
        //Student Function
        function studentArray(){
            const student = [{
                firstName :"", 
                lastName  :"",
                ID        :0,
                Exams     :0 
            }]

            while(true){
                student.firstName = prompt("Enter First Name : ");
                student.lastName  = prompt("Enter Last Name  : ");
                student.ID        = prompt("Enter ID         : ");
                student.Exams     = calculateExamgrade(grade);

                if(student === "e" || student=== null){
                    break;
                }
                student.push(student.firstName);
                student.push(student.lastName);
                student.push(student.ID);
                student.push(student.Exams);
            }

            //Displays array
            for(i = 0; i < studentArray; i++){
                console.log(i+1 + studentArray[i]); 
            }
        }
        //Calculate the grade of the exams
        function calculateExamgrade(grade){
            let TestGrades = [];
            while(true){
                let input = prompt("Add Grades")
                if(input ==="e" || input === null){
                    break;
                }
                TestGrades.push(Number(input));
            }        
            //Calclate the arrays
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i in TestGrades){
                sum += TestGrades[i];
            }
            //Calculate average grade
            grade = Math.round((sum/TestGrades.length));
            //Return grade letter
             switch(true){
                case grade >= 90:
                    console.log("You recived an A")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 89 && grade >= 80:
                    console.log("You recived a B")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 79 && grade >= 70:
                    console.log("You recived a C")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 69 && grade >= 60:
                    console.log("You recived a D")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 59:
                    return grade;
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the while loops, they will remain true forever, what prompted you to use true in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I solve the problem in your code and write comments explain the part that has issue in your code, have a look

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        //Initilization of Grades
        let grade = 0;
        //Start of the function
        studentArray();
        //Student Function
        function studentArray() {
            // Student value need to change so don't use const, however u can use push function with const variables
            // Here u declare array of object, do u aware of this?
            student = {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                ID: 0,
                Exams: 0
            }

            // In this situation u already assign the value to student.firstName and so on, so there is no need for u to use push function
            student.firstName = prompt("Enter First Name : ");
            student.lastName = prompt("Enter Last Name  : ");
            student.ID = prompt("Enter ID         : ");
            student.Exams = calculateExamgrade(grade);

            //display the object
            console.log(student)

        }
        //Calculate the grade of the exams
        function calculateExamgrade(grade) {
            let TestGrades = [];
            while (true) {
                let input = prompt("Add Grades")
                // change the === null to == null (try google why, because I'm busy I have class to attend :)
                if (input === "e" || input == null) {
                    break;
                }
                // Check if the input is convertible to integer or not if yes push to array, if no prompt input again without pushing the input
                if (Number(input) === NaN) {
                    continue
                } else {
                    TestGrades.push(Number(input));
                }
            }
            //Display Array
            console.log(TestGrades)

            //Calclate the arrays
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i in TestGrades) {
                sum += TestGrades[i];
            }
            //Calculate average grade
            grade = Math.round((sum / TestGrades.length));
            //Return grade letter
            switch (true) {
                case grade >= 90:
                    console.log("You recived an A")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 89 && grade >= 80:
                    console.log("You recived a B")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 79 && grade >= 70:
                    console.log("You recived a C")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 69 && grade >= 60:
                    console.log("You recived a D")
                    return grade;
                    break;
                case grade <= 59:
                    return grade;
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is wrong !

Comment: @Ankit hey, this is my first time trying to contribute to the community. So feel free to correct me

Answer (score 0):

Working with `prompt()` generally does not create a good user experience. But this seems to be an exercise, so here is my suggestion on how to simplify and fix your code:

```js
const data=[];
const props=[["fn","First name?"],["ln","Last name?"],["id","Id?"],["scores","Grades?"]];

function getStudent(){
 const a={};
 for ([k,q] of props){
  // const q=props[k];
  if (k=="scores") { let t;
   a[k]=[];
   while(t=prompt(q)) a[k].push(+t);
   if (a[k].length){
    a.avg=a.scores.reduce((a,c)=>a+c)/a.scores.length;
    // grade calculation as a one-liner:
    a.grade="ABCD"[9-Math.floor(a.avg/10)]??"";
   }
  } else
   a[k]=prompt(q); 
   if (!a.fn) return false
 }
 return a;
}

for (let s;s=getStudent();) data.push(s);

console.log(data);
```

You can input several student data. The loop will be terminated by clicking "cancel" when asked for the first name.